# IIS 10 automatically adds wrong CORS header

Tags: wcf, iis, cors

I have installed IIS CORS moudule on the server.

On the OPTIONS request I get :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ### the actual good origin ###
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 06:32:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

But on the POST request I get

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/
Content-Length: 1216
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 06:32:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

In web config i have

```
  <cors enabled="true">
  <add origin="### the actual good origin ###" allowCredentials="true" >

    <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    <allowMethods >
        <add method="GET" />
        <add method="HEAD" />
        <add method="POST" />
        <add method="PUT" /> 
        <add method="DELETE" />         
    </allowMethods>
  </add>
</cors>
```

The WebService I try to call is an WCF webservice.

How can I disable the "localhost" header on the POST request?
I am not setting anything static header, neither in web.config nor in IIS itself

Comment: you could try to add the header using iis HTTP response header. Access-Control-Allow-Origin and the value null. for more detail you could refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to add the **Global.asax** file to the WCF project, which is used to solve the CORS issue.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With,Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
```

Alternatively, we could also configure it in webconfig file.

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
            }

        }
```

**Webconfig.**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.